# SQL Server Job Agent don't execute SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, package, jobs

I have a problem with one SQL Server Agent Job. There is one step which executes a SSIS package, I receive a successful message but the SSIS package don't be executed.

The SSIS package owner is local administrator on our SQL Server - he is also member of the sa group and the Microsoft SQL Server job will be executed with this user.

I don't know why this SSIS package will not be executed... In this SSIS package there will be executed two other packages but these ones are in the same directory. I also checked the boxes in the connection manager options at the job step properties.

If I execute the package manually with the execute package utility everything works fine.

On a few pages some people write that I have to create an proxy account but is this really necessary and if there is a problem by using this user why don't occur an error?

I hope anyone has an idea. Thank you!

Comment: How do you know it don't work?

Comment: In this tasks there will be imported 120 files in variuos tables. Also timestamps will be set..

The first step is a file task which copies all files from a network path to our local drive.

This package runs 50 minutes and it takes only 5 seconds at the job agent.

Comment: So the package does execute, does not error, but you're not getting the expected results. It appears your issue stems from accessing network resources. Are you performing this through a network share (\\server\share\) or through a mapped drive (S:\)? For the packages that work fine, are they accessing a network resource? If they are, are they going to the exact same location as this package?

Comment: In the first version I mapped the network drive, because the shared network directory has to be connected by an other user.

Then I thought that this is maybe the problem. So I get read/write access on the network path for my SSIS package owner. 

I changed also the path from X:\ (mapped network drive) to \\server\directory. If I manually execetue this package there is no problem and all files will be copied from \\server\directory to D:\tmp (local drive), the packages are also there.

But the issue still exists. There are no errors (not one in these packages and no error in the job history).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for this problem. I created a batch file which executes this packages with the dtexec.exe

Then I created a task (in the server task scheduler) which executes the batch file - now I have an automatically daily import without any problems.